# Frames of reference and inhomogeneity and anisotropy of space

Tags: classical-mechanics, spacetime, reference-frames

I was reading mechanics by Landau and Lifshitz where I encountered this statement, "If we were to choose an arbitrary frame of reference, space would be inhomogeneous and anisotropic." I tried to think of random frames but couldn't come up with something which could help me understand the above statement. Can someone explain the gist of the statement made above, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a noninertial frame (one accelerating in an arbitrary direction for instance).  In this frame the expansion of space would appear different in different directions and would change with time.